# Linux tcp settings for ipv6

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I want to change tcp keepalive settigs specifically tcp_keepalive_time, tcp_keepalive_intvl, tcp_keepalive_probes and tcp_retries2 settings for linux. all these settings are available for ipv4 in linux but i dont see any ipv6 settings. Do these settings automatically apply to ipv6? If these settings do apply to ipv6 is there an official doc which mentions that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the tcp settings for ipv4 also apply to ipv6:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt:

```
...
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/* Variables:

IPv6 has no global variables such as tcp_*.  tcp_* settings under ipv4/ also
apply to IPv6  
...
```